# Is there an existing ActionScript framework to develop quickly desktop applications?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frameworks

I'm new in ActionScript, and I have a project where I have to develop a feature for an offline desktop application that would look like this :

> Group 1    | Subgroup 3.1    | Item 3.3.1    | Some infos (text, picture)
>   displayed about selected item
>
> Group 2    | Subgroup 3.2 > | Item 3.3.2    |
>
> Group 3 > | Subgroup 3.3    | Item 3.3.3 > |

It'd be in the form of several columns where each column would be a deeper level in the tree view, and the last column would display some information about the selected item.

The deadline of the project is quite short, that why I'd like to know if there's an existing ActionScript framework that can easily implement this so that I can have more time to work on other features, or if I have to do it myself.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Flex](http://flex.apache.org/). New version was released just 2 months ago. However, you still need to know Actionscript (plus the Flex library). There is no drag'n'drop GUI designer.